# Add HttpModule to web.config in Nop

Tags: web-config, httpmodule, nopcommerce

The issue seems to be that the syntax

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

is looking in the site bin folder, however as far as I can tell nop
 commerce only puts a plugins dll in the Plugins folder.

What I've tried, that hasn't worked so far

- putting the syntax in the web.config that exists in within the plugin folder
- wrapping the syntax in the `<location path="...">` tag

I realize that I could pull the class out into it's own project and manually drop the compiled dll into the bin, but I'd like to avoid this.

Has anybody used httpmodules within a Nop Commerce Plugin?